# Head busting MYSQL error 1064 What's Wrong with my Syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, mysql-error-1064

I've been staring at this for a moment and think I'm not perceiving the obvious.

The resulting display is 1064 (mysql reference says it's a syntax error)

```
$query = "INSERT INTO members ( id , username , password , all , articles ) VALUES ( ";
    $query .= "'' , " ;
    $query .= $username . "' , '" ;
    $query .= $password . "' , '" ;
    $query .= $allVals . "' , ";
    $query .= "'' );";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if (mysqli_errno($con)){
            echo mysqli_errno($con);
            echo mysqli_connect_error($con);
    }
```

I should note that $allVals is an encoded json object.

What's wrong with **my query**?

Comment: Have you echoed it out? You don't seem to have initial quotes for any of the values you're passing in. But since you're using mysqli, why aren't you using a prepared statement?

Comment: *Where* is the syntax error exactly? Please post the whole error message.

Comment: Additionally, you probably don't need to be inserting anything into the id column, assuming that it's an auto_incremented field.

Comment: Thanks all. It was the missing apostrophe. Unofficially answered***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a single quote after `$username`, but not before:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO members ( id , username , password , all , articles ) VALUES ( ";
    $query .= "'' , '" ; //missed the quote here
    $query .= $username . "' , '" ;
    $query .= $password . "' , '" ;
    $query .= $allVals . "' , ";
    $query .= "'' );";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if (mysqli_errno($con)){
            echo mysqli_errno($con);
            echo mysqli_connect_error($con);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$query .= "'' , " ;
```

You miss here a single-quote.

```
$query .= "'' , '" ;
```

Should do the job.

I'd also consider to use prepared statements to better see where your syntax error may be; when you try to build your query like this, is will be probably more difficult to debug it.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO members ( id , username , password , all , articles ) VALUES ( '', ?, ?, ?, '')");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $password, $allVals);
$stmt->execute();
/* ... */
```

Comment: `id` is still not necessary, as described in Andrewsi's comment.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I don't know if it's a primary key with auto-increment.

Answer (score 0):

You must put common after every values.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO members ( id , username , password , all , articles ) VALUES ( ";
$query .= "'' , '" ;
$query .= $username . "','" ;
$query .= $password . "', '" ;
$query .= $allVals . "' ";
$query .= ")";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if (mysqli_errno($con)){
        echo mysqli_errno($con);
        echo mysqli_connect_error($con);
}
```

Comment: btw Not the downvoter, but this character "," is called **comma**, not *common*. And the correct form is "after every value", not "values".

Comment: It's OK, not problem ))

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't inserting data into `id` or `articles` columns, don't include them as part of your query statement:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO members ( username , password , all ) VALUES ( '";
    $query .= $username . "' , '" ;
    $query .= $password . "' , '" ;
    $query .= $allVals . "' );";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if (mysqli_errno($con)){
            echo mysqli_errno($con);
            echo mysqli_connect_error($con);
    }
```

Additionally, you need to make sure your variables are properly escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I like doing it this way:

```
    $query .= "('' , '".$username . "' , '" .$password . "' , '".$allVals . "' ,'' )";
```

It also lends itself to things like inserting multiple rows :

```
$qvals[] = "('' , '".$username[1] . "' , '" .$password[1] . "' , '".$allVals[1] . "' ,'' )";
$qvals[] = "('' , '".$username[2] . "' , '" .$password[2] . "' , '".$allVals[2] . "' ,'' )";
$qvals[] = "('' , '".$username[3] . "' , '" .$password[3] . "' , '".$allVals[3] . "' ,'' )";

$query = "INSERT INTO members ( `id` , `username` , `password` , `all` , `articles` ) VALUES ".implode(',',$qvals);
```

You can double check the result by checking what `echo $query;` outputs.